# Uniform vs. $l^p$-Convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n\subset l^p(\mathbb{Z})$ be a sequence with $f_n\to g$ in $l^\infty(\mathbb{Z})$. Further assume $g\in l^p(\mathbb{Z})$. How can i show $f_n\to g$ in $l^p(\mathbb{Z})$? Or is this even false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this only holds if you're working over a compact space. Since $\mathbb Z$ isn't compact, function wise, this isn't going to be true. For instance: Let 
$$
f_{n_i}=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt[p]n} &1\leq i \leq n\\\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Thus $\|f_n\|_p=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. But in the sup norm ($\ell^\infty$), this converges to the $0$ sequence, which has $\ell^p$ norm $0$.

Let's try to make this more compact. Suppose we let $\mathbb Z_N$ be the space of $N$-length sequences. Assume $f_n\to g$ in the $\ell^\infty$ norm. Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and let $\|f_n-g\|_\infty<\varepsilon$.Then
$$
\|f_n-g\|_p=\left(\sum_{i=1}^N |f_{n_i}-g_i|^p\right)^{1/p}\leq\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\varepsilon^p\right)^{1/p}=\varepsilon\cdot\sqrt[p]N.
$$
Since $\sqrt[p]N$ is a constant for any $N$, $f_n\to g$ in any $\ell^p$ norm.

Comment: This is a good exapmle. But what would be the right assumption to obtain $l^p$-convergence?

Comment: I added an example. Make sense?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense for me. It seems like you assume, that the $f_n$'s and $g$ are in $\mathbb{Z}_N$?

Comment: Yes, I am making that assumption. $\ell^\infty$ convergence does not imply $\ell^p$ convergence in a non-compact space.

Comment: Then it makes sense. But on compact spaces one could use Hölder's inequality (that is what you do)

Comment: Indeed. Things go wonky when you can stretch out to infinity in your domain.